# Eclipse does not detect my sony xperia C2004 device

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, usb-debugging

Eclipse is not able to detect my  phone xperia C2004 device.
I have installed sony PC companion. The PC companion detects my phone and I am able to transfer the media .

-I have enabled the debugging mode on my device .
-USB connection mode is Mass Storage Mode (MSC).
-running adb devices in cmd does not show up my device.
-in device manager other device option only shows up Android 
-In portable device my phone shows up.

I have done all the above but still I am not able to detect the device on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before (quite a few times) - There's a nack to it! What you'll need is some kind of usb device listing program, something like "lsusb". Then:

1. Run lsusb in a command prompt (It'll output something like below):

   C:\Users\Loki\Downloads\lsusb>lsusb
   lsusb
   VendorID:046d ProductID:c05b
   "USB Input Device"   "Logitech"    "USB Optical Mouse"
2. Get the vendor id from the output, for your device.
3. Next, navigate to: "C:\Users\.android" (I'm presuming a windows environment, sorry)
4. Inside there you may/may not a file called: **adb_usb.ini** (if not, create it, it's fine). If you do have it, open it up.
5. Inside this file you need to ensure that each vendor ID (for problematic devices) is listed on a newline: So once, you've got your vendor id, type: 0xVENDORID (so in my case it would be: 0x046d and save the file.

After that you should be good. This works for me all of the time, but I have heard of some other odd devices that wont be seen even after this either. Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: I used the USBDeview utility to view my android phone's vendor id which is 0fce and added it in adb_usb.ini file but still I am not able to view the device.

Comment: Finally I was able to run my android app on my device .. Only after installing another application. EasyTether.http://easytether.blogspot.in/2010/10/easytether-drivers.html